# change document file name via workflow - SharePoint Online

Tags: document-library, designer-workflow

Is it possible to change the filename of document uploaded in sharepoint online/onpremises using workflow?

We would like to have documents uploaded to sharepoint but unfortunately some have the same name and this from a folder structure :(

When i used a workflow and use set i keep getting error.

Thanks in Advance